# fire alarm manager in every 5 min android

Tags: android

i want to make a service which fire alarm manager in every 5 min interval when my application is running only..so how to do it?

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, OnetimeAlarmReceiver.class);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);

  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), sender);
   Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Why do you need a service? You do NOT need a service just to have an alarm going off every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 5*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```

that alarm will be repeating forever until you cancel it, so you need to cancel it on getting the event when you no longer need it.

Comment: how to stop running service?when i exit from app

Answer (score 2):

```
private class ProgressTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // set your time here
                    int currenSeconds = 0
                    fireAlarm(currenSeconds);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Inizialize :

```
     Timer progressTimer = new Timer();
     ProgressTimerTask   timeTask = new ProgressTimerTask();
     progressTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timeTask, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: wont work in service check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924295/service-of-an-app-stops-when-phone-is-not-being-charged for the reason why

Answer (score 2):

Cancel the `AlarmManager` in `onPause()` of the activity.

A much better solution would be to use a `Handler` with `postDelayed(Runnable r, 5000)` since you said only when your application is running.  `Handlers` are much more efficient than using `AlarmManager` for this.

```
Handler myHandler = new Handler();
Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
   @Override
   public void run(){
      // code goes here
      myHandler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
   }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle){
   super.onCreate(icicle);
   // code
   myHandler.postDelayed(myRunnable, 5000);
   // to start instantly can call myHandler.post(myRunnable); instead
   // more code
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   // code
   myHandler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable); // cancels it
   // code
}
```

Comment: wont work in service, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14924295/service-of-an-app-stops-when-phone-is-not-being-charged) for the reason

Comment: This wasn't meant to be run in a Service.  He was asking how to call something every 5 minutes **only when the app is running**. Starting a Service would have been overkill as the other answers were saying.

Answer (score 0):

Set Alarm repeating every 5 minutes in Kotlin

```
val intent = Intent(context, OnetimeAlarmReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), (1000 * 60 * 5).toLong(), pendingIntent)
```

To cancel Alarm

```
        val intent = Intent(context, OnetimeAlarmReceiver::class.java)
        val sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        alarmManager.cancel(sender)
```